# GetPositionAsync TaskCancelException

Tags: android, exception, xamarin.android, gps, location

I am encountering a problem is that the system will throw the TaskCancel exception back when I am trying to get the location info.
At the time, I try to open Google map（someone answered it can be solved by opening Google map) without connecting to Internet, and go back to APP to try again to get the location. The result is still give me back the exception.
Then, I make the smartphone to connect to the Internet, and then open Google map again, and then go back to APP to get the location. I can get the location info now!!!

The problem of not getting the gps location is not happened in every smartphone, but in the Vivo V2050(with Android11).

Anyone know about this problem?
How to fix it?

```
try
{
var locator=CrossGeolocator.Current;
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMillseconds: 10000);
var long=position.Longitude;
}
catch (TaskCancelException ex)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you provided, you use the Xam.Plugin.Geolocator.

For now, we recommand use `Xamarin.Essentials` instead.

After request the permissions and declare the hardware features in the manifest file, you could use the code below to get the current position.

```
   CancellationTokenSource cts;

 async Task GetCurrentLocation()
 {
     try
     {
         var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
         cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
         var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request, cts.Token);

         if (location != null)
         {
             Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}");
         }
     }
     catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
     {
         // Handle not supported on device exception
     }
     catch (FeatureNotEnabledException fneEx)
     {
         // Handle not enabled on device exception
     }
     catch (PermissionException pEx)
     {
         // Handle permission exception
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
              // Unable to get location
     }
 }

 protected override void OnDisappearing()
 {
     if (cts != null && !cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    cts.Cancel();
     base.OnDisappearing();
 }
```

For more details, you could check the MS docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=android